# QML Model with json/javascript properties

Tags: javascript, json, qt, qml, javascript-objects

I'm writing a desktop application in Qt and QML, where the user can put markers on the map, connect these to each other to build a net. Each marker will have is own id and the id of the markers that it's connected to, along with its own coordinates. This list of markers will later on be passed on to another program, preferably in json or something similar.

What is the best way to do this? Is it possible to set these attributes/properties in my marker model somehow?

This is how it looks right now:

```
enterimport QtQuick 2.5;
import QtLocation 5.6
import QtQuick 2.0

MapQuickItem {
    id: marker
    property MapComponent overlay: null
    property variant markersConnected
    property variant polylinesConnected
    property int connectedCount: 0
    property int markerID: 0

    anchorPoint.x: rect.width/2
    anchorPoint.y: rect.height/2

    sourceItem: Rectangle {
        id:rect
        color: "LimeGreen"
        width: 10
        height: 10
        rotation: 45
        border.color: "Black"
        smooth: true
        opacity: markerMouseArea.pressed ? 0.6 : 1.0


        MouseArea  {
            id: markerMouseArea
            property int lastX: -1
            property int lastY: -1
            anchors.fill: parent
            hoverEnabled : false
            //drag.target: marker
            preventStealing: true
            //Drag.active: markerMouseArea.drag.active

            onClicked : {
                overlay.pressX = mouse.x
                overlay.pressY = mouse.y
                if(overlay.delegateIndex == 3) {
                    //disconnect Marker, then delete it
                    overlay.deleteMarker(markersConnected, polylinesConnected, markerID)
                } else if(overlay.delegateIndex == 1){
                    // marker has been pressed
                    if(overlay.currentMarker != -1) {
                        overlay.previousMarker = overlay.currentMarker
                    }
                    overlay.currentMarker = -1
                    for (var i = 0; i< overlay.markers.length; i++){
                        if (marker == overlay.markers[i]){
                            overlay.currentMarker = i
                            if(overlay.previousMarker != overlay.currentMarker) {
                                overlay.connectMarkers()
                            } else {
                                //same marker was pressed twice
                                overlay.currentMarker = -1
                                overlay.previousMarker = -1
                            }
                            break
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    function connectMark(Marker) {
        connectedCount ++
        markersConnected.push(Marker.markerID)
        if(markersConnected.length > 2) {
            rect.color = "Red"
        }
        createJson()
        //printConnections()
    }

    function connectMarker(MarkerTo) {
        connectMark(MarkerTo)
        MarkerTo.connectMark(this)
    }

    function isConnectedTo(Marker) {
        //return markersConnected.contains(Marker)
        if(this == Marker) {
            return true
        }
        for (var i = 0; i< markersConnected.length; i++){
            if (Marker.markerID == markersConnected[i]){
                return true
            }
        }
        return false
    }

    function connectedMarkers() {
        return connectedCount
    }

    function returnID() {
        return markerID
    }

    function printConnections() {
        console.log(markerID, " is connected to: ")
        for (var i = 0; i< markersConnected.length; i++){
            console.log(markersConnected[i], ", ")
        }
    }

    function disconnectMarkers() {
        for(var i = 0; i<markersConnected.length; i++) {
            var marker = markersConnected(i)
            marker.disconnectMarker(this)
        }
    }

    function disconnectMarker(MarkerID){
        markersConnected.pop(MarkerID)
        if(markersConnected.length < connectedCount)
            connectedCount --
        if(markersConnected.length < 3) {
            rect.color = "LimeGreen"
        }
    }

    function connectPolyline(polylineID) {
        polylinesConnected.push(polylineID)
        //console.log(markerID, "is connected to line nr ", polylineID)
    }

    function disconnectPolyline(polylineID) {
        polylinesConnected.pop(polylineID)
        //console.log(markerID, "is disconnected from line nr ", polylineID)
    }

    Component.onCompleted: {
        markerID = overlay.markerCounter
        markersConnected = new Array();
        polylinesConnected = new Array();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your marker model?

Comment: You can create ListModel and so [append](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-models-listmodel.html#append-method) your points to it. As you see that "eats" JS object. So just loop through you list and append the points. I advice you to provide a minimal working code and Json example to get an answer here.

Comment: at the moment my marker is a MapQuickItem with a Rectangle as its sourceItem. Is it possible to put this in a ListModel somehow?

Comment: I've now added my current code @folibis

Comment: I've now added my current code @eyllanesc

Comment: what is `MapComponent`?

Comment: It's pretty much just a Map @eyllanesc